# Redirecting after upload

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to redirect after a file upload but when I try to redirect on AngularJS side, it is not working.

Node.js :

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('propt'), function (req, res) { 
     res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8"});
     res.send();
});
```

AngularJS :

```
$scope.uploadFile = function () {
        var fichier = $scope.monFichier;
        var uploadUrl = "/upload";
        console.dir(fichier);
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', fichier);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" }
        })
            .then(function () {
                $window.location.href = '/users.html';
             });

    }
```

**UPDATE : The "then" part is not executed** (I tried with a simple `console.log()` to test it)

Comment: where you want to redirect the page.do you want to redirect to /users

Comment: No I want to redirect the page to /user

Comment: check and tell me does it working or not

Answer (score 0):

you redirect the page by using this code

```
 $window.location.href = '/users.html';



window.location.href = '/users.html';
```

Comment: I'm using .html

Comment: It's not working too, I will try to get the referer url and redirect into that

Comment: did you add " $window" or " $location" inside your controller's function

Comment: Yes I add $window, if I didn't I would have an error in the console of my browser

Comment: did you add "$location" ??

Comment: Yes, there is both $window and $location.

Comment: insert your (HTML) file location in the code. don't paste direct url(users.html)

Comment: have you check the file location

Comment: file location isn't the problem, when I put a console.log in the then, it's not executing

Answer (score 0):

Try `$location`

You would need to inject `$location` in the controller and   `$location.path('/user')` would redirect to `http://example.com/#/user`

```
.then(function () {
 $location.path('/user');
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to redirect with Node.js instead of AngularJS ?

Comment: Node is server side scripting, aren't you trying to redirect the view to user view so that's angularjs

Comment: Yep but after the upload, the url of the page is "/upload" like the POST method on Node.js but I don't have angularjs routes for "/upload"

Comment: That's bad practice, you should keep the API routes and view routes different.

Comment: They are different, I just want to mean that when I'm on /upload because the upload just finished, this page have got nothing to do with AngularJS so I can't redirect

Comment: I found a server-side function `res.redirect()`, how do I redirect on a AngularJS URL ?